# VF - Apex:Repeat that uses the parent Apex:Repeat as filter?

Tags: apex, visualforce

Ok, I am trying to figure out how to have a child apex:repeat only show records when they belong to the parent apex:repeat.

Here is a screenshot of my current result. The dates belong to "The Acorn Tree" account but as you can see they are also being shown for "The Apple Pie" account.

[image]

I don't really have an idea on how to resolve this. I am trying to not do a query for every single account as I believe I will run into SOQL limits. The repeat in question is the one called "!OEs".

Here is my controller code:

```
public class LicensingGridController {

    public List<BCS__c> getTheHubs() {
        List<BCS__c> hubs = [Select Id, Name, User__r.Name,
                             (Select Id,Account__r.Name,Hub_Name__r.Name
                              FROM Account_Counselors__r),
                             (Select Name 
                              FROM Licenses__r)
                             FROM BCS__c
                             WHERE Inactive__C = FALSE];
        return hubs;
    }

    public list<OE_Rollover_Spans__c> getOEs(){
        List<OE_Rollover_Spans__c> OEs = [Select Account__c,Name,OE_Type__c,Start_Date__c,End_Date__c
                                         FROM OE_Rollover_Spans__c];
            return OEs;
    }

}
```

Here is my page:

```
<apex:page controller="LicensingGridController" sidebar="false">
    <apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!TheHubs}" var="Hub">
            <apex:column value="{!Hub.Name}" />
            <apex:column>
                <apex:facet name="header">Licenses</apex:facet>
                <ul>
                    <apex:repeat value="{!Hub.Licenses__r}" var="Lic">
                        <li><apex:outputField value="{!Lic.Name}" /></li>
                    </apex:repeat>
                </ul>
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column>
                <apex:facet name="header">Accounts</apex:facet>
                <ul>
                    <apex:repeat value="{!Hub.Account_Counselors__r}" var="Counselor">
                        <li><b><apex:outputField value="{!Counselor.Account__r.Name}"/></b></li>
                            <apex:repeat value="{!OEs}" var="OE">
                                <li><apex:outputField value="{!OE.Start_Date__c}"/> -through- <apex:outputField value="{!OE.End_Date__c}"/></li>
                            </apex:repeat>
                    </apex:repeat>
                </ul>
            </apex:column>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand the data model so i might be speaking way-off but see if this makes sense:

Looking at the code i dont see correlation between Account_Couselors__r and records in OEs list.

What you might want to consider is build a map, between account counselors and corresponding list of OE's and use that map to display data in the page.

For example:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!mapAcntCounselors.keyset()}" var="CounselorName">
          <li><b><apex:outputField value="{!CounselorName}"/></b></li>
    <apex:repeat value="{!mapAcntCounselors.get(CounselorName)}" var="OE">
           <li><apex:outputField value="{!OE.Start_Date__c}"/> -through- <apex:outputField value="{!OE.End_Date__c}"/></li>
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:repeat>
```

Comment: `{!mapAcntCounselors[Counselor.Name]}` (or, even better, use the Id value for uniqueness).

Comment: Account_Counselor__c and OE_Rollover_Spans__c both have a lookup to Account.

Comment: Just to be clear, I don't want the OE dates to show per Account_Counselor__c. It should be showing per each Account.  The overall goal is to show which counselors are on which accounts, and then for each of those accounts what are the upcoming OEs.